# Laravel Query Builder to Eloquent Builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How can I convert following Laravel DB Query Builder to Eloquent?

Is it possible to do Laravel Eloquent?

```
$reports = DB::table('clicks')
            ->select('offer_name', DB::raw('offer_name as offers, COUNT(id) as clicks, SUM(IF(status = 1, 1, 0)) as lead, SUM(IF(status=1, payout, 0)) as earnings'))
            ->groupBy('offer_name')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change on `DB::table('clicks')` to Eloquent Builder. `select` and `groupBy` is same for Eloquent.

Now make a model of clicks using command.

```
php artisan make:model Click
```

It'll create `Click.php` file in **App** folder. It looks like this as I mention below.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Click extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'clicks';

}
```

Now your query looks like this.

```
$reports = \App\Click::select('offer_name', DB::raw('offer_name as offers, COUNT(id) as clicks, SUM(IF(status = 1, 1, 0)) as lead, SUM(IF(status=1, payout, 0)) as earnings'))
            ->groupBy('offer_name')
            ->get();
```